# Installing Homebrew using RVM?

Tags: imagemagick, rvm, homebrew

I already installed and am using RVM.  For a new app I am working on, I want to install ImageMagick, carrierwave, rmagick, etc. and was told installing it using Homebrew was easiest.

I don't currently have Homebrew but heard a lot of good things about it so wanted to install it.  My question is, do I have to install homebrew using RVM and if so, how?  Or, do I simply just paste in:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/gist/323731)"
```

to my terminal command line and everything should work?

Please let me know if there are caveats to any of the other things I want to install as well.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I just installed it by putting this in the root of my terminal window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RVM will not install Homebrew.

RVM will install your Ruby instances in its sandbox, and gems to be used with those instances will be automatically routed to the sandbox. The gems that interface to ImageMagick can be installed with RVM, but you'll need to rely on Homebrew to install their underlying libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was looking to install homebrew itself.  Does it mean I just install homebrew using the code I mentioned in my question?  I guess what I am asking is, do I install homebrew system-wide?

Comment: If you are revising your question, please edit your original question and append the changes there. That will help anyone who looks at it.